# Scala / DataFrame / Spark: How do I express multiple conditional aggregates?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a table like:

```
id,date,value
1,2017-02-12,3
2,2017-03-18,2
1,2017-03-20,5
1,2017-04-01,1
3,2017-04-01,3
2,2017-04-10,2
```

I already have this as a dataframe (it comes from a Hive table)

Now, I want an output that looks like (logically):

```
id, count($"date">"2017-03"), sum($"value" where $"date">"2017-03"), count($"date">"2017-02"), sum($"value" where $"date">"2017-02")
```

I've tried to express this in a single agg(), but I just can't figure out how to do the inner conditionals. I know how to filter ahead of the aggregation, but that doesn't do what I need with the two different sub-ranges.

```
// doesn't do the right thing
myDF.where($"date">"2017-03")
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(sum("value") as "value_03", count("value") as "count_03")
  .where($"date">"2017-04")
  .agg(sum("value") as "value_04", count("value") as "value_04")
```

In SQL I would have put all the aggregation into a single SELECT statement with conditionals inside the `count`/`sum` clauses. How do I do something similar with `DataFrames` in Spark with Scala?

The closest I can think of is calculating membership for each tuple in each of the windows before the `groupBy(`), and summing over that membership times value (and straight sum for count.) It seems like there should be a better way to express this with conditionals inside the `agg()`, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In SQL I would have put all the aggregation into a single SELECT statement with conditionals inside the count/sum clauses.

You can do exactly the same thing here:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{sum, when}

myDF
  .groupBy($"id")
  .agg(
    sum(when($"date" > "2017-03", $"value")).alias("value3"),
    sum(when($"date" > "2017-04", $"value")).alias("value4")
  )
```

```
+---+------+------+
| id|value3|value4|
+---+------+------+
|  1|     6|     1|
|  3|     3|     3|
|  2|     4|     2|
+---+------+------+
```

Comment: Great! And I can chain "when()" statements where in SQL I'd use CASE. And when() can optionally terminate in otherwise().